# sed: renaming selective strings in a file

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a file called `protein.faa`, its content is:

```
>WP_004066472.1 MULTISPECIES: NADH-quinone oxidoreductase subunit K [Thermococcus]
MIPLQFVTAFLMIFMGIYAFLYKRNLIKLILALNLI
LVLTSIVIGVCVLSLAMALTINAYRHYGTLDVNKLRRLRG
>WP_004066568.1 MULTISPECIES: DNA-directed RNA polymerase subunit P [Thermococcus]
MVEALYKCAKCGKEF
>WP_004066764.1 MULTISPECIES: Lrp/AsnC ligand binding domain-containing protein [Thermococcus]
MVTAFILMVTAAGKEREVMEKLLTYPEVKEAYVVYG
>WP_004067064.1 MULTISPECIES: hypothetical protein [Thermococcus]
MEITIEKFKPKVTRPFKRKNEYWVKL
PSAKELVDEYFSE
```

I want to rename **only** names after each `>` to filename+its order number, i.e.:

```
>protein_1 MULTISPECIES: NADH-quinone oxidoreductase subunit K [Thermococcus]
MIPLQFVTAFLMIFMGIYAFLYKRNLIKLILALNLI
LVLTSIVIGVCVLSLAMALTINAYRHYGTLDVNKLRRLRG
>protein_2 MULTISPECIES: DNA-directed RNA polymerase subunit P [Thermococcus]
MVEALYKCAKCGKEF
>protein_3 MULTISPECIES: Lrp/AsnC ligand binding domain-containing protein [Thermococcus]
MVTAFILMVTAAGKEREVMEKLLTYPEVKEAYVVYG
>protein_4 MULTISPECIES: hypothetical protein [Thermococcus]
MEITIEKFKPKVTRPFKRKNEYWVKL
PSAKELVDEYFSE
```

My code is

```
name="$(echo protein.faa | sed 's/....$//')"
sed "s/>.*/>${name}/" protein.faa
```

which allows me to get only

```
>protein
MIPLQFVTAFLMIFMGIYAFLYKRNLIKLILALNLI
LVLTSIVIGVCVLSLAMALTINAYRHYGTLDVNKLRRLRG
>protein
MVEALYKCAKCGKEF
>protein
MVTAFILMVTAAGKEREVMEKLLTYPEVKEAYVVYG
>protein
MEITIEKFKPKVTRPFKRKNEYWVKL
PSAKELVDEYFSE
```

How do I add order numbers and keep whatever goes after `>protein_i`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This job suites `gnu awk` more:

```sh
awk -i inplace 'BEGINFILE {fn=FILENAME; sub(/\..*$/, "", fn); i=0} $1 ~ /^>/{$1 = ">" fn "_" ++i} 1' *.faa

>protein_1 MULTISPECIES: NADH-quinone oxidoreductase subunit K [Thermococcus]
MIPLQFVTAFLMIFMGIYAFLYKRNLIKLILALNLI
LVLTSIVIGVCVLSLAMALTINAYRHYGTLDVNKLRRLRG
>protein_2 MULTISPECIES: DNA-directed RNA polymerase subunit P [Thermococcus]
MVEALYKCAKCGKEF
>protein_3 MULTISPECIES: Lrp/AsnC ligand binding domain-containing protein [Thermococcus]
MVTAFILMVTAAGKEREVMEKLLTYPEVKEAYVVYG
>protein_4 MULTISPECIES: hypothetical protein [Thermococcus]
MEITIEKFKPKVTRPFKRKNEYWVKL
PSAKELVDEYFSE
```

To make it more readable for `gnu awk`:

```sh
awk -i inplace 'BEGINFILE {
   fn = FILENAME
   sub(/\..*$/, "", fn)
   i = 0
}
$1 ~ /^>/{
   $1 = ">" fn "_" ++i
} 1' *.faa
```

For `non-gnu` awk:

```sh
for f in *.faa; do
   awk 'BEGINFILE {fn=FILENAME; sub(/\..*$/, "", fn)} $1 ~ /^>/{$1 = ">" fn "_" ++i} 1' "$f" > _tmp && mv _tmp "$f"
done
```

Comment: but this way it only suits if the file is indeed called protein.faa, but what if it's a custom name (plus I do it in a loop over all *.faa files in a dir)?

Comment: check my updated answer for doing it to multiple `*.faa` files.

Comment: it works well without `-i inplace` and with it it returns an error.

Comment: I made it run in a loop over all `.faa` files saving each time to a tmp file: `awk... $f > tmp && mv tmp $f`

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned `-i inplace` is gnu extension so if you're not using `gnu awk` then that option won't work. A loop would work fine as you've suggested. I will update answer further for non-gnu awk.

Answer (score 1):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN { $i = 1; chomp( $basename = `basename $ARGV[0] .faa` ); } s{^>\S+}{>${basename}_${i}} and $i++; ' in.faa > out.faa
```

To change file in-place:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 'BEGIN { $i = 1; chomp( $basename = `basename $ARGV[0] .faa` ); } s{^>\S+}{>${basename}_${i}} and $i++; ' in.faa
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)

Comment: only one comment: it replaces identifiers after `>` to `protein_X` while I need to put there the `filename_X`

Comment: @plnnvkv Updated the answer.